# Creating an element once inside of a php while loop

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to set up a slideshow inside of a wordpress loop. To do so, I want to have one section of the slide content, and one section that does the navigation.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="upcoming_shows">
        <?php if ( $shows->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>               
            <?php while ( $shows->have_posts() ) : $shows->the_post(); ?>
                <?php //get rid of auto drafts and trash posts
                    $p_status =  get_post_status( $post );
                    if ($p_status != 'trash' and $p_status != 'auto-draft') : 
                ?>
<!--I WANT A containing DIV HERE created only once-->
               <div id="slides">
                    <div class="slide" id="slide-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <p class="show_date"><?php echo get_field('show_date'); ?></p>
                        <h1 class="band_names"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="link to blog post page"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    </div><!--end Slide-->
<!--AND IT WILL END HERE-->
               </div><!-- end SLIDES CONTAINING DIV--> 
<!--THEN ANOTHER DIV HERE CONTAINING THE SLIDES_NAV-->
<div id="slides_nav"> <!--CREATE THIS ONLY ONCE as a wrapper-->
 <p class="band_names"><a href=#slide-"<?php $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
</div><!--end slides nav CONTAINER-->
                <?php endif; ?><!--end Auto Draft check-->
            <?php endwhile; ?>          
            <?php endif; ?><!--end if haveposts-->


        </div><!--end upcoming_shows-->
```

What I would like to do is wrap the elements with a class of "slide" in a div called "slides", and then create another set of elements wrapped in a div called "slides_nav".

I can't figure out a way to say :

"If this is the first iteration of the loop, create a div called "slides" around the all the "slide" elements.

"If this is the first iteration of the loop, create a div called "slide_nav" to wrap the slide navigation elements" (which will also be created inside the loop (they will be the title of the $shows post and a page-internal link to the slide with an ID matching the slide_nav href.)

I tried:

```
<?php $i=0;
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo '<div id="slides">';
        $i++;
    };
```

and it correctly created the div, but did so for each slide ( I also added the conditional to close the div).

I am a beginner to PHP fyi.

I looked at some answers to create something once inside of a loop, and tried a few, but I believe my lack of programming knowledge may have me missing a simple solution.

Thanks

Comment: The reason the div was created for each slide is because it's still in the while loop. It'll be re-run for each slide.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create it before the loop?

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="slides">';
    while( // the loop ){
        // your instructions
    }
```

Comment: I did that for the containing div for the entire section; WITHIN that section (and the loop) I want 1 div that will wrap all the slides, and then one div that will wrap the slide_nav. I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: @Squadrons So just put them between the first `if` and the `while` loop.

Comment: I added some code to my example to make it more clear. WITHIN the loop I want to create two divs ONE TIME ONLY, not for every iteration of the loop. This needs to happen inside of the loop so that I can call elements from within the loop for the content inside of each of these divs.

Answer (score 0):

For any other people new to PHP who might stumble upon this, here is what I found to be the best answer.

Creating the div outside the loop is far easier than any other possible solution. While I could conditionally get the slides div to show up inside the loop and contain each slide div, the logic to do so would only work once in that loop.

If I wanted to expand upon that and have two conditionally created divs, it got so much more complicated that I began to realize that it was simpler to just create an additional loop for any other information I needed.

The reason I asked this question was because I assumed that creating two loops to get the same information from the same DB query was bad practice.

I don't know if creating those two separate loops is considered good practice or not still, but I do know that it is FAR easier to program for.

If anyone can tell me whether that is a good or bad practice (running redundant queries and loops on the same information) to simplify the process of creating good (or necessary) markup, I will credit you with the correct answer.

Thanks.